# REST API way to go / state of the art for multiple requests

Tags: rest

Im building a REST Api atm. I have a few entities that have attributes like state or type. These are enums and can only have predefined values. Like closed, open, in progress etc.
Im wondering what is the way to go for an API. Offering one editing route, where I set the state. Something like

```
 /entity/state/{id}?state=XXX
```

and the request change the state of the entity with {id} to XXX.
Or is it better to have multiple different routes for each state, like:

```
/entity/state/{id}/close    
/entity/state/{id}/open    
/entity/state/{id}/inprogress
```

I can find arguments for both method, but I dont know what the current way to go us. Any recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that either is fine!

Usually when I have something that is a bit like a collection, and I am filtering that thing, I tend to prefer to use query parameters, especially if the filters are optional and there are many.

However, there are also cases where I want to make something clearly stand out as it's own thing.

So there's no hard rules, and no right answers and the decision will probably depend more on your own aesthetic preference.

Comment: Kinda thought the same. Thanks!